# Cannot get returnRejectedSubmitPromise to work

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have been banging my head all day today trying to figure out why I can't catch the rejected promise that is supposed to come back from a failed submit when you set [returnRejectedSubmitPromise](http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/api/reduxForm?_k=ytx1z8) to true.

I set the returnRejectedSubmitPromise to true in my config object.

```
export default reduxForm({
  returnRejectedSubmitPromise: true,
  form: 'addSite',
  fields: formFields,
  validate: AddSiteValidation
}, mapStateToProps)(SiteAdd);
```

I have a submit function that I pass to the handleSubmit prop that redux form gives you. I call the handleSubmit on the onSubmit of my form. No matter what I do I either get `handleSubmit(...).catch is not a function` or an unhandled rejected promise error.

Is there any example out there of how to catch the rejected promise?

Comment: What's the return value of the function you're passing to to `handleSubmit`?  I haven't used this particular option personally, but it looks like it will only return a rejected promise if you are returning a promise from the function you pass to `handleSubmit`.  See:  https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/handleSubmit.js#L11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the below link as it answers your question directly.

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/616#issuecomment-209105697